# GNOME Evoluion extensions: Are there any open-source extensions I can choose?

Tags: gnome, email, evolution

I would like to find any GNOME Evolution extensions already available. I am looking in particular for an extension that would print threads of messages (all or selected messages) as a single document. Can you give me links I can browse? Thanks.